# Can you use Apple pay/Google play with a client (React app) not connected to the internet/offline?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Our system is connected to the internet only certain times a day. So we need to queue payments until there is a conection, but the problem is the front-end (React) can't be built without fetching data from stripe to make the button for instance. Is there a way to decouple the client/front-end entirely from the internet (the server works without internet by pre generating the client secret tokens when there IS a conection

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about what your integration looks like? Are you accepting online payments or in-person payments?

For example, Are you using Stripe Terminal and process in-person payments? If so, I believe they have a beta [1] feature that allows operating offline. You'd likely need to reach out to their support team to check if you're eligible.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/features/operate-offline/overview

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was talking about online payments on the web, no in-person payments.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't think there's a way to queue transactions offline for online payments unfortunately. You could record PAN/Card information offline and then send it over to stripe to create card tokens [1] and use that for payments. But I don't think that's the recommended approach as you'd need to maintain PCI compliance yourself etc. If you're okay with maintaining compliance stuff, You'd likely want to reach out to stripe support team to ask for more details on this.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card

Comment: Thanks for your help @hanzo but i need to use apple pay/google pay so I should get the card information somehow but I don't think that is possible...

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to tokenize the card without an internet connection. unfortunately. So yeah, this isn't a supported usecase currently.